# Export Excel file to pdf including Print titles

Tags: python, excel, pywin32, win32com

I have an invoice in an excel file that I need to convert into a pdf. The problem is, that I set some Print titles to repeat on every page but if I use my code these don't show in the pdf. How can I make them show?

This is my current code:

```
from win32com import client
excel = client.Dispatch(EXCEL_APP)
sheets = excel.Workbooks.Open(invoice.xlsx")
work_sheets = sheets.Worksheets[0]
work_sheets.ExportAsFixedFormat(0,invoice.pdf")
sheets.Close(True)
```

All help is greatly appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

`ip install aspose-cells`

`pip install -Iv jpype1==0.7.0`

```
#Load Excel file
workbook = Workbook("Book1.xlsx")

#Convert Excel to PDF
workbook.save("xlsx-to-pdf.pdf", SaveFormat.PDF)
```

You can fine more information and function [here](https://blog.aspose.com/2021/04/02/convert-excel-files-to-pdf-in-python/)

Comment: What modules do I have to import for this to work? and does it cost?